requestError: Invalid object name al ejecutar consulta
Estoy trabajando en un CRUD de práctica usando Node. Cuando ejecuto me aparece:

“error ejecutando la consulta requestError: Invalid object name
Control_de_Documentos”

Ya revisé mi base de datos: está bien escrito el nombre de la tabla, pero me sigue mostrando ese error.
En la terminal se suele ver así:

Aquí desconozco si fue un problema de implementación o simplemente mi error está en otra parte del código.
Mi controlador es este:
app.post('/explorar', async (req, res) => {
  const parameter = req.body.parameter;
  
  try{
      let pool = await sql.connect(configsaproj);

      //Consulta para ejecutar

      const result = await pool.request()
      .input('parameter', sql.Int, parameter)
          .query(`
              
           SELECT 
              CD.Folio AS FolioDocumento, 
              mat.Folio AS FolioAT, 
              mat.NUAT AS NuatAT, 
              mat.Fecha_de_Registro AS FechaRegistroUnatd,
              emp.nuat AS NUAT, 
              emp.fecha_de_registro AS FechaRegistroMP, 
              emp.Numero_de_Denuncia AS Acta, 
              emp.nic AS CarpetaInvestigacion,
              DD.Observaciones
           FROM 
              Control_de_Documentos CD 
              INNER JOIN Detalle_de_Documentos_MPO DD ON CD.Folio = DD.Archivo 
              INNER JOIN expediente_ministerio_publico emp ON DD.Expediente_MP = emp.clave 
              INNER JOIN Modulo_Atencion_Inicial mat ON DD.Modulo_Atencion_Inicial = mat.Clave
           WHERE 
           CD.Folio = @parameter
           `)
      if (result.recordset.length ===0){
          res.redirect('/NHR');
      }else {
          res.render('respuesta', {resultados: result.recordset});
      }

  }catch (err) {
      console.error('Error ejecutando la consulta', err);
      res.status(500).send('Error en el servidor');

  } 
});

app.get('/NHR', (req, res) => {
  res.render('NHR');
});

  // Iniciar el servidor
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor escuchando en http://localhost:${port}`);
});

En mi vista tengo el siguiente script donde se mostrarán los resultados obtenidos:
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Busqueda Sobre Texto de documento</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilosDB.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="search-container">
    
            <div class="search-bar">
                <div class="search-option">
                    <input type="radio" id="search1" name="search" checked>
                    <label for="search1">Búsqueda por número de acta, carpeta o NUAT (sólo SAPROJ)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="search-option">
                    <input type="radio" id="search2" name="search">
                    <label for="search2">Búsqueda sobre texto de documentos (sólo SAPROJ)</label>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <form action="/explorar" method="post">
                <div class="search-field">
                    <label for="parameter">Parámetro a encontrar</label>
                    <input type="text" id="parameter" name="parameter"placeholder="Valor a encontrar">
                    <button type="submit">explorar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    
        <script src="scriptR.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

